# simplify fraction (stone drops off a cliff)

Tags: derivatives

How do I get from
$$ \frac {dt} {T} = \frac {dx} {gt} \sqrt { \frac {g} {2h} } $$
to
$$ \frac {dt} {T} = \frac {1} {2 \sqrt {hx} } dx $$
where $x(t) = \frac {1} {2} gt^2 $ and $ T = \sqrt { \frac {2h} {g}}$.

I'm currently struggling with Griffiths' *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*. This is from a worked example on p.11-12 of the 2nd edition.

Comment: this notation is hardly close to a formal mathematical notation. I think it will be better to migrate this question to the stackexchange physics portal, as they will understand the kind of notation used there. By example, rigorously speaking, the notation $\frac{dt}T$ seems some kind of differential form

Comment: $\frac {1} {2 \sqrt {hx}} $ is a probability density derived from $ x(t) = \frac {1} {2} gt^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
x=\frac{1}{2}gt^2
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
gt^2=2x
$$
so
\begin{align*}
\frac{dt}{T}
&
=\frac{dx}{gt}\sqrt{\frac{g}{2h}}
=\sqrt{\frac{g}{g^2t^2\cdot2h}}\,dx
=\sqrt{\frac{1}{gt^2\cdot2h}}\,dx
\\&
=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2x\cdot2h}}\,dx
=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4hx}}\,dx
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4hx}}\,dx
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{hx}}\,dx.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

It’s just algebra. I figured out the steps to get the first expression  for $dt\over T$ from the second, but you can reverse the steps. Using what you are given for $x(t)$ and $T$, and assuming $t\ge0$,

$$\frac {dt} {T} = \frac {1} {2 \sqrt {hx} } dx = \frac {1} {{2 \sqrt {h\left({1\over2}gt^2\right)}} } dx = \frac {1} {t\sqrt {2hg} } dx=\frac {1} {gt\sqrt {2h\over g} } dx=\frac {\sqrt {g\over 2h}dx} {gt }.$$